# How can I check that the application is resumed from memory?

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

In my application I have a filter function on table view which give filtered result in table. I set filtered options(checkboxes) in shared preferences so the next time the user go in filter screen it sees the checkboxes checked so it know what was the table filtered for and what he did check last time for filtering.

when the application launches i set them all to unchecked(requirement), but i dont know when the application is launched or resume. when the application is resumed from memory it again initialized all my data types. how can i check the application is resumed. if i set things in activity onResume - no gain it is called every time i just want to know only when the application is resumed.

What happens now i dont know when the application is resumed from memory, my filter behaves like application launched and set all to unchecked

Answer (score 1):

what i did is, on my first activity made a boolean and put false and stored it in shared preferences, then did it true when start that filtering thing. so it remains true as the application remains in the memory and resume even. when application exits, and the launched again on startup it again turns false

Answer (score 0):

There's no "resumed from memory" state. It is either resumed or created (or restarted). So you should rework your application logic and init your stuff on `onCreate()` instead of `onResume()`

Answer (score 0):

You can restore your checkboxes on [onRestart()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestart%28%29), that means your activity was not killed and is resumed after it had been stopped(either manually or by android).

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand you question properly, but as far as my understanding goes, you are filtering user options through shared preferences. If this is so, you need not unset/set each option programatically. Android remembers and and restores this for you. If you want to access these, just call `context.getSharedPreferences()` and from sharedPreferences object received call `getBoolean (key,defValue)`.

Comment: i want to know when the application is resumed from memory, if the user minimized it earlier.

Comment: oh ok... then you can try onRestart event of the activity